# Docker: does COPY support variable destinations?

Tags: docker, copy

Is it possible to specify a variable dest-dir in a Dockerfile's `COPY`?

E.g. given this Dockerfile:

```
ARG dest_dir=/foo/bar/

FROM alpine:3.7 as base
COPY ./ ${dest_dir}
```

...`docker build` doesn't seem to recognize the variable destination:

```
$ docker build .
[+] Building 0.3s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 118B                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.7                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:3.7                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 106B                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [2/2] COPY ./                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.1s
 => => writing image sha256:e761939bd6a8092e51e37b08d3b4ca196d310d5e36d232252313cdddd68adace                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
```

The thing to note in the above is that in step 2/2, the `COPY` doesn't have a second argument.
I've tried double-quoting the `ARG` value, its use in the `COPY` statement, and both, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an `ARG` appears before the `FROM` statement, it only applies to the FROM statement proceeding it. If you want an `ARG` statement to apply in the rest of the file, [it must appear after the FROM statement](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact).

Like this:

```
FROM alpine:3.7 as base

ARG dest_dir=/foo/bar/
COPY ./ ${dest_dir}
```